# Audio setup issue with PS4

Tags: ps4, audio-hardware

I recently purchased a PS4.

For audio, I have been using either the PS4 wireless headphones, or a cheap Bluetooth speaker that I connect through an AUX cable connected to the PS4 controller.

What I would like to set up is most likely an entry level surround sound, 2.1 or 3.1.

The issue is that I connect my PS4 to a monitor that only has 1 HDMI port, and don’t quote me on this, but I believe the PS4 slim has one HDMI port also.

I have no way of connecting a speaker system to the monitor, directly at least.

How could I connect the speakers If I only have exactly one pair of HDMI ports?

Comment: Does your monitor have an audio out?

Comment: @MadMrCrazy no it doesn’t, only ports it has is one HDMI port, and a VGA-port.

Comment: I think you can use USB speakers directly plugged on one of the PS4 USB ports. Didn't try myself but seems to work from what I've seen here and there on other sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can buy (at least in the UK though I assume they're available worldwide) a HDMI Audio Extractor.  This takes in the HDMI signal and loops through the video signal and has a separate audio output for connecting your speakers to.

Alternatively, you could go the full way and buy a 5.1 (or greater) surround sound system which will include an amplifier which does everything for you.

Comment: So, correct me if I’m wrong, basically I would plug my PS4 up to the extractor, the extractor would split the PS4 outgoing signal into two, and I would be able to connect monitor and speaker to extractor? One signal(video) would go to monitor, and the other to speaker?

Answer (score -1):

HDMI extractor is the best way you can do, you can purchase one with multiple HDMI ports you can checkout amazon.